# Reading a string from long string in C

Tags: c, string

I have a long string where I need to copy the string until \n or EOF

here is what I got

```
char static_ip[20]="9.2.1.333";
int index=0;
while (*ptr_place!='\n' && *ptr_place!=EOF){
  static_ip[index]=*ptr_place;
  index++;
  ptr_place++;
}
static_ip[index]='\0'
```

any better idea of how to do it?

the text will be like

> 44.11.5.856
>       bla bla = 22.11.444.8
>       olala

And I want to end the program when static_ip contain only 44.11.5.856 without newline or w/e

Comment: I think, you don't need an array of pointers

Comment: what is `ptr_place`?

Comment: The EOF "character" does not exist and will never be found in a string. The end of string marker is a null byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asked for a solution for three text examples, one of which does not contain an IP address. This code extracts the IP address and returns the pointer to the static string, otherwise returns `NULL`. It also returns `NULL` if the substring is too long for the static string.

It could be more sophisticated and check the substring is a valid IP address format. I just extracted a sequence of numbers and periods, and I leave that to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLEN  19

char *getIP(char *ptr_place)
{
    static char static_ip[MAXLEN+1];                // static array
    int len = 0;

    while (!isdigit(*ptr_place)) {                  // stop at first digit
        if (*ptr_place == '\0')                     // check for end of string
            return NULL;                            // no digits found
        ptr_place++;
    }

    while (isdigit(ptr_place[len]) || ptr_place[len] == '.')  // IP address chars
        if (++len > MAXLEN)                         // check substring length
            return NULL;                            // won't fit target string

    memcpy(static_ip, ptr_place, len);              // copy substring to static str
    static_ip[len] = '\0';                          // terminate it
    return static_ip;
}

int main()
{
    char *text[3] = {"44.11.5.856", "bla bla = 22.11.444.8", "olala" };
    int i;
    char *p;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        p = getIP(text[i]);                         //test the function
        if (p)
            printf("IP address: %s\n", p);
        else 
            printf("IP address: NULL\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
IP address: 44.11.5.856
IP address: 22.11.444.8
IP address: NULL
```

Note that the static string content will not survive another call the function.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
char* static_ip[20]="9.2.1.333";
```

use

```
char static_ip[20]="9.2.1.333";
 // ^^ no *
```

Also,

```
while (*ptr_place!='\n' && *ptr_place!=EOF){
```

is not right.

`EOF` is meant to detect end of file while reading data from a file. It is usually defined as `-1`. Comparing a `char` to `EOF` does not seem right.

```
while (*ptr_place!='\n' && *ptr_place!= '\0'){
```

seems like what you need. You should also add a check to make sure you don't use `static_ip` out of bounds.

```
while (*ptr_place!='\n' && *ptr_place!= '\0' && i < 19){
```

Add a line to null terminate `static_ip` after the `while` loop.

```
static_ip[i] = `\0';
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh, He's updating `static_ip` from `ptr_place`. He might need more characters than the length of `"9.2.1.333"`.

Comment: @RSahu following that logic, `static_ip[16]` should suffice, isn't it?why it has to be `20`? :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, that should work too, as far as I can see.